# oracle - getting 1 or 0 records based on the number of occurrences of a non-unique field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table MYTABLE

```
N_REC | MYFIELD |
1     | foo     |
2     | foo     |
3     | bar     |
```

where N_REC is the primary key and MYFIELD is a non-unique field.
I need to query this table on MYFIELD and extract the associated N_REC, but only if there is only one occurrence of MYFIELD; otherwise I need no records returned.
So if I go with MYFIELD='bar' I will get 3, if I go with MYFIELD='foo' I will get no records.

I went with the following query

```
select * from 
   ( 
   select 
     n_rec, 
     ( select count(*) from mytable where mycolumn=my.mycolumn ) as counter 
   from mytable my where mycolumn=? 
   ) 
where counter=1
```

While it gives me the desired result I feel like I'm running the same query twice.
Are there better ways to achieve what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also try the analytic or windowing version of count(*) and compare plans to the other options:

```
select n_rec, my_field
from (select n_rec, my_field
        , count(*) over (partition by my_field) as Counter
    from myTable
    where my_field = ?)
where Counter = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that this should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    my_field,
    MAX(n_rec)
FROM
    My_Table
GROUP BY
    my_field
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: n_rec is the primary key, so group by should be done on MYFIELD. select myfield, max(n_rec) from mytable where myfield=? group by myfield having count(*) = 1